# How to extend all Sequelize Models?

Tags: javascript, object, sequelize.js, extend

I added several Sequelize extension methods, db-ext.js:

```js
module.exports = {
    findResult: (filter, col = 'id') => {
        filter.raw = true;
        return this.findOne(filter).then(row => {
            if (!row) return null;
            return row[col] || null;
        })
    },
    ...
};
```

then, in the models/index.js, I would like to add those methods to all the models:

```js
...

let sequelize;
if (configEnv.use_env_variable) {
    sequelize = new Sequelize(process.env[configEnv.use_env_variable], configEnv);
} else {
    sequelize = new Sequelize(configEnv.database, configEnv.username, configEnv.password, configEnv);
}

fs
    .readdirSync(__dirname)
    .filter(file => {
        return (file.indexOf('.') !== 0) && (file !== basename) && (file.slice(-3) === '.js');
    })
    .forEach(file => {
        const model = sequelize['import'](path.join(__dirname, file));

        //----- TODO: this one not working. What to do here, or anywhere?
        Object.keys(dbExt).forEach(item => {
            model[item] = dbExt[item];
        })

        db[model.name] = model;
    });
...
```

When starting the node, error was output:

```js
You have triggered an unhandledRejection, you may have forgotten to catch a Promise rejection:
TypeError: this.findOne is not a function
at ...
```

I hope I make myself clear. Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to achieve what your looking for is using DAOS.

Create a dao class to any of your models. The class's methods for model A will be the queries you do to table A which is represented by model A. Each class will explicity extend a base dao class with the methods you want the derived class to inherit.

For e.g

```
class BaseDao {
       constructor(model) {
             this.model = model
       }

       create(data) {
             return this.model.create(data);
       }

       findAll(options) {
             return this.model.findAll(options);
       }

       myGreatMethod() {
             // Do whatever you need
       }
}
```

And now:

```
class ADao extends BaseDao {
       costructor(model) {
              super(model);
       }

       // Other great methods related to A    model
}
```

Usage:

```
var sequelize = require('models/index.js);

let AModel = sequelize.import('path/to/model');
let aDao = new ADao(AModel);
aDao.myGreatMethod().then().catch();
```